# how to avoid pressing several time enter affects the input data?

Tags: java

I'm writting a JAVA Class to validate input data, especifically integer numbers. 
The class I develop is running fine but when I press more than one time enter and then a char type, it display several times " Error!! Invalid number. Try again. " and I would like to avoid it.

I have use nextLine() method but it doesn't seems to correct it.

Here is the Class:

```
package chapter07.libro;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Validator_integer 

{

    public static int getInt (Scanner scanner, String promt)

    {
        int numberInteger = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;

        System.out.println(promt);
        while(isValid == false)
        {
            if(scanner.hasNextInt())
            {
                numberInteger= scanner.nextInt();
                isValid = true;
            }//if

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error!! Invalid number. Try again.");
            }//else
            scanner.nextLine();         
        }//while

        return numberInteger;   
    }//getInt

}//Validator_integer
```

and next is the app to use the class:

```
package chapter.prueba;

import java.util.Scanner;

import chapter07.libro.Validator_integer;

public class Test_Validator_Integer

{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String choice = "y";

        while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            int number = Validator_integer.getInt(sc, "Enter integer number: ");
            System.out.println(number);

            System.out.println("Continue (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();

        }//while

    }//main

}//Test_Validator_Integer
```

The results I get are next:

```
Enter integer number: 

2

2

Continue (y/n): 

y

Enter integer number: 

(Here I press several time enter)

xx

Error!! Invalid number. Try again.

Error!! Invalid number. Try again.

Error!! Invalid number. Try again.

Error!! Invalid number. Try again.

2

2

Continue (y/n): 

n
```

So the part of (Error!! Invalid number. Try again.) displayed several times, is the one I would like to avoid.

Does any one know how to fix it???
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried to flush the System.in before attempting a read? That way, any buffered/queued inputs will be erased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you read from System.in, make sure to "clear" it's contents to get rid of buffered/queued-up input. If there are n characters queued-up, then skip that many chars and you'll need to enter something new.

```
int n = System.in.available();
System.in.skip(n);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Comment: Thanks Markus, in order to delete the quenue (generated by pressing the  enter key several times) I have found simpler to add the next code within the else statment:    `code`                                             else
   {
    
    String string = scanner.nextLine();    //NEW
    while(string.isEmpty())     //NEW
    {          //NEW
     string = scanner.nextLine();  //NEW     
    }//while        //NEW 
    
    //scanner.nextLine();     //DELETE
    System.out.println("Error!! Invalid number. Try again.");
   }//else  `code`